# Cookie is not saved in Browser Cookie : Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I have trouble in weird issue. I am using Forms Authentication in ASP.NET. After validate user, I am using below code.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(requestInfo.Username, requestInfo.RememberMe);
```

In Browser, I am able to get Set-Cookie header.

```
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=3FEC1547348829DD49CC997DCE03489A6CB8B78AF6681A34DB270F4897F8E8A909CA063651252246164256C317AEF4C702DCC0877C3926FF754EF1254FDF137913178B87FEAAE4067B664CD8E56B908CDE8928D570AF81DA6720FC129E8A24F9C2A4CE53B1D95E58E910A1ABABAC7F9E7EB3FBA65C956B8F38BDBEF5111F51F15490CB5A07CEF3996C8A78B5430DB973C43BE0DA3F5386D1697A24B1486C; expires=Thu, 23-Apr-2020 09:10:21 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

But Cookie is not being saved in Browser's Cookie. I've tried with localhost, 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.5

Kindly any expert help me.

Update:  I have added domain livesite.com. but it is still doesn't work.

```
.ASPXAUTH=5D2D5D5409720F7AEC0875D30FEB852961EBDE014CDA41E2FC5B7A44CBE7852D6532AB19B0887D1E12893E10F42A204B5486DF814DE5F9B712CA3FD23729DC7A2E5E4CA9B4273459DCB792175AA770386164A9575A63C78A75CFADF20C6BC1C58681E8F3F2CA33F91037FCD8F767E6B2162AF0240A5C6F4B2F9638E7A82E0C8B7B3F14E7FD7DD5BBBE6ECB086A8EF21E1736D6AE2C302E047CB1D44EB18; domain=.livesite.com; path=/; HttpOnly


<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="240" domain="livesite.com" requireSSL="false"/>
</authentication>
```

Host File:

```
127.0.0.1 livesite.com
```

Website is runing:

```
http://livesite.com:9000/#Site
```

API is running:

```
http://livesite.com:1534
```

I have tested in Mozilla also. But cookie doesn't save in browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the setting on your `web.config` that are correct. Usually if you have not setup the `domain`, or if you have set the `requireSSL` different from you call, you may not been able to set the cookie.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="example.com" requireSSL="true" name=".myauth" />
</authentication>
```

Now, the domain is better to bee with out the subdomain `www.` in front because you set this up for any name. I hope that you have set some local `iis` and you use a local dns for the name.

the `requireSSL="true"` means that only `https` cookie can be set. If you have no ssl for test, turn it off.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I am using localhost. ** <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="240"/>
    </authentication>
   **  I don't want to use https in localhost. do i need to add domain as localhost?

Comment: @user1629977 yes, the domain is crucial to accept and read the cookie

Comment: Tried with domain="192.168.0.5" and domain="localhost" but it does not working. Kindly check sir

Comment: Updated answer. please have a look please

Comment: @user1629977  must set `domain="livesite.com"`

Comment: Sir, changed domain "livesite.com" but it doesn't work. Please have a look where i am doing incorrect.

Comment: Finally I have fixed issue. Adding Domain was fixed but there were CORS issues as well. Thanks Sir